# question on triangles regarding locus of a point

Tags: geometry

Let AB be a fixed line segement.Let P be a moving point such that Angle(APB) is equal to a constant acute angle. Then find the locus of P. I am stuck in a couple of equations using cosine rule of triangles.

Comment: Do you know what the curve is when the angle is $90^\circ$?

Comment: That seems to be two straight lines.

Comment: @user367810 Think at it geometrically before writing equations. Maybe you'll recall some other construction where the angle $\angle APB$ doesn't change when $P$ moves with $A,B$ fixed.

Comment: no john,i dont.

Comment: @user367810 Hint: for $90^\circ$ the locus is the circle of diameter $AB$ (minus the two points).

Comment: dxiv, my answer is coming out to 0=x^2+y^2-bx where b is the length of the line segment and (x,y) are the coordinates

Comment: yes you are right dxiv.

Comment: @user367810 Complete the square in $x\,$: $\,x^2-2\cdot \frac{b}{2}x + \color{red}{?}^2 + y^2=\color{red}{?}^2\,$. Now think at inscribed angles for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a theorem of high-school Plane Geometry. If two points $A$ and $B$ lie on the circumference of a circle centered at $\Bbb O$, and if $\angle A\Bbb OB=\theta\le\pi$, then at any point $P$ on the circumference exterior to the arc from $A$ to $B$, you get $\angle PAB=\theta/2$; if $P$ is within the arc, the angle is $\pi-\theta/2$, the supplement of the other angle. The converse is valid, too, so that your locus is an arc of a circle.

Comment: your answer is wrong.